# i'm creating a module in openerp and i want to know the diffrence between one2many and many2one and many2many and how to relie between classes?

Tags: python, module, odoo

Please have a look

```
class produit_produit(osv.osv):
    """le produit"""
    _name = 'produit.produit'
    _columns = {
        'product_id': fields.char('product_id',size=30,required=True, help='product_id'),
        'product_libelle': fields.char('product_libelle',size=60,required=True, help='product_libelle'),
        'type': fields.char('type',required=True, help='type'),
        'prix': fields.many2one('produitachete.produitachete',help='prix'),
    }
produit_produit()

class produitachete_produitachete(osv.osv):
   """produit achete"""
   _name = 'produitachete.produitachete'
   _columns = {
       'prix_achat': fields.char('prix_achat',size=30,required=True, help='prix_achat'),

   }
produitachete_produitachete()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Better format your code example

Comment: The question is so generic, you can search for the odoo documentation for that.